# Saving object in a class variable and using it in another function - php, laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So here's the code

```
use App\Video;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
protected $video;

public function index()
{
// $video_to_watch is fetched from db and I want to save it and use it in  
// another function in this controller

$this -> video = $video_to_watch;

return view('home', compact('video_to_watch'));
}

public function feedback(Request $request)
{
 dd($this -> video);
}
}
```

feedback returns null for some reason.

when I put the

```
dd($this -> video);
```

in index() it works fine, not null.

I have tried what's suggested here: [Laravel doesn't remember class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031350/laravel-doesnt-remember-class-variables?answertab=votes#tab-top)

but it didn't help.

I'm sure it's something stupid I'm overlooking. But can't seem to figure out what, any help much appreciated.

Comment: _Just in case_: are you call `index()` and `feedback()` actions during the same request?

Comment: Two different requests I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't keep your `$video` value between 2 different requests. You have to fetch your video data in each request.

```
use App\Video;

class HomeController extends Controller
{    
    public function index() {
        $myVideo = $this->getMyVideo();    
        return view('home', $myVideo);
    }

    public function feedback(Request $request) {
       dd($this->getMyVideo);
    }

    private function getMyVideo() {
        // fetch $video_to_watch from db         
        return $video_to_watch ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know that, I am new to MVC and Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't fetch data inside a Controller. It's only 'a glue' between model and view. Repeat. **No fetching inside a controller**.

Use domain services and dependency injection to get business data and if you want to share this data create shared service (single instance).

-

Putting a data object into a controller property class makes a temporary dependency between method calls. Avoid it. Use services instead.

Comment: Thanks, understood. I am new to MVC and Laravel, can you elaborate a bit more on when to use domains services and dependency injection if you have time?

Comment: "Don't think about caching if you're using an ORM library." - why?